# Can we do bulk write and read from same Postgres Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We run a cron every 15min which get some data from somewhere and inserts into the main table(basically appends), which is then used for reading in production.
So not to perform read and write in the same table, we use 2 tables(temp and main).
First we get data and insert into temp table, then we rename temp and main table(using a 3rd table), so basically temp becomes main and main becomes temp, and then we make temp equivalent to main(basically truncating temp, and inserting everything from main), so in the end we have identical data in both table.

I am not sure if this is the correct, but is there any better way of doing this?

We are not performing read and write on same table because there can be bulk write which can happen(because of cron) and at that time our read performance can be affected

Comment: What is the problem with reading and writing the same table at the same time?

Comment: Please explain detailly, before inserting data to the `main` table are your delete all data on the `main` table? If only data is added to the table then you should not have a problem. If you delete data before inserting it, so this is not correct business logic and this method is a very bad performance method. Because you can check existing data on `main` table and after then can insert only new data.

Comment: @RaminFaracov no we are not deleting anything from main table, whenever we get some data we basically have to append the new data to the existing data, so the process we follow is to insert it into a temp table(which has same data as main) and then renames temp to main table (and then make the data same in temp as main)
Please tell me if this is correct way ?
Thank you

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe bulk inserts happen on the table, can we perform bulk insert and read from the same table ? This table is used live in production.

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that.

Comment: My sympathies to documentation writers who spend the time to create the answers to many questions only to have the answers not read. See [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html): '...  MVCC locks acquired for querying (reading) data do not conflict with locks acquired for writing data, and so reading never blocks writing and writing never blocks reading.'